# SCSS class isn't being applied inside a @mixin

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying switch a background image for my child element if my parent has the `active` class. This child 'active' classes needs to be done in a @mixin as it will be used throughout the stylesheet but the class isn't being applied.

Example HTML

```
<div class="active">
  <a class="link1">link1</a>
  <a class="link2">link2</a>
</div>
```

My SCSS

```
  .link1 {
    background-image: url('/image.png');
  }

...

  @mixin activeLinks {
    .active .link1 {
    background-image: url('/active_image.png');
    }
  }
```

This doesn't update the image for the link. But if I were to move the styling outside of the `@mixin`, it works totally fine. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sass/showsass.php?filename=demo_sass_mixin2

Answer (score 0):

the `mixin` is for storing a static code and you added to your elements with the `@include`

Example

```
<div class="active">
  <a class="link1">link1</a>
  <a class="link2">link2</a>
</div>
```

//The mixin needs to be outside of any tag, class, or bracket because you might be planning to use it in other sections. `in my case I place all my mixin on an external sheet  and add it with import` however you can place the `mixin` at the bottom of scss file

```
   @mixin links {
        color: red;
      }
```

//add the `mixin` with @include, this will call the mixin and apply the red color

```
.active{
  .link1{
  @include links;
  }
}
```